# How to hide Dart pop up notification in Visual Studio Code

Tags: dart, notifications, popup, settings, hide

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NOvQ.png]

How can I turn this popup notification off?
Im using Visual Studio Code Version: 1.64.2 (user setup)
Commit: f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326
Date: 2022-02-09T22:02:28.252Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22000

Flutter: Channel Stable Version 2.10.2

Answer (score 0):

This feature is actually from VS Code and not the extension. It looks like there are a few settings in VS Code to control its behaviour:

[from vscode settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NghEw.png)

From github issue https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3757

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).